# Cannot get Hello World in localhost using Tomcat

Tags: tomcat9

I cannot get Hello World page on `localhost`.

I have ran tomcat and get `Apache` home page on `localhost: 8080`. In IntelliJ I have created a new Maven project from archetype web-app. I have added configuration Smart Tomcat. Here, there is an un-editable (grey) field called Tomcat Server with value `null`.

What should I do to get a web page with hello world? Should i create or edit any files?

Answer (score 0):

Read this: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/sample/

You might just forgot to add the path to the URL.

You can try this to: https://tcserver.docs.pivotal.io/3x/docs-tcserver/topics/tutwebapp.html

Hope it helps!

Brhaka